# Issue with the Python any() function

Tags: python, list, any

I am trying to convert a list of lists into a single list with '1's if **any** of the elements in a single list is 1 and 0 otherwise. I have the following list:

```
result =[[-1, -1, 0], [1, 0, -1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

and if I use `any()` on the first list

i.e. `result[0]`, I get True even though it is supposed to be false. `any(result[0])` gives `True`.

However, when I test each element separately, I get False in each case

i.e. `result[0][0] == True` gives `False` and similar result for the remaining elements. I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why is any supposed to be false on the first list? Test out bool(-1)

Comment: `result[0][0]` will give back -1. Why would -1 == True be true ? Both of your assumption, first and second are wrong

Comment: having a look at [Truthy and Falsy Values in Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) should explain the problem here, and give you a better understanding of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

`any` tests if any value is truthy, not if any value equals `True`.  All non-zero integers are truthy so `any([-1, -1, 0])` is `True`.

See for details [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) which applies to `any` and `all` as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, why your attempts didn't work:

```
bool(X) = True if x != 0; else False.
```

Then `any(result[0])` will return True, as there is at least one non-zero element in the list.

Your second test `result[0][0] == True` cannot work, as `result[0][0] = -1`, then not `True` (Not even boolean in fact). So it returns `False`.

To do what you want, you can use `any` with list comprehension:

```
result = [1 if any(y == 1 for y in x) else 0 for x in result]
>>> [0, 1, 1] For your example
```

EDIT:
According to Kelly Bundy's comment, another way to do it:

```
result = [1 if 1 in x else 0 for x in result]
```

You can also use boolean, but you only can reach True/False (or 1/0)

Comment: Or simply `[int(1 in x) for x in result]`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this was possible. Thanks. However, this method only allows to reach 0 & 1 (int(True/False)), a if/else clause allows to get any value you want